# Python - Loading an R-Tree from file

Tags: python, r-tree

I was able to successfully build an R-Tree spatial index and save it to a file.

```
from rtree import index

idx = index.Index("gridIndex")
idx.insert(..., ...)    
idx.insert(..., ...)
and so on...
```

Now I can load the saved index and use it:

```
idx = index.Index('gridIndex')
hits = idx.intersection([x, y], objects=True)
```

This works only if my index is in the same directory as my python file.

In my case, I'm running the main python file from a different directory:

```
python path/to/my_file/main.py
```

Now the index is not loaded, rather it creates an empty index in my working directory.

So how can I load my previously created index and specify its path?

I've tried to load it this way:

```
idx = index.Index(os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'gridIndex')) # doesn't work
```

And also this way:

```
idx = index.Index(os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'gridIndex.dat'))
```

Which creates a new empty index - two new files in the desired directory: gridIndex.dat.dat and gridIndex.dat.idx

In the documentation I found two methods - dumps() and loads(), but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question about r-trees but about how relative paths work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `index.Rtree`!

something like this :

```
from rtree import index

idx = index.Rtree('path/to/gridIndex')
hits = idx.intersection([x, y], objects=True)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this way I get an error: UnpicklingError: invalid load key

Comment: This is also not the right way, because the Index doesn't have a load() method, only loads();

Comment: @Dusan so, you maybe can use the `index.Rtree`?!

Comment: I did try it just now, but it behaves the same way as index.Index(); If I put the full path for the gridIndex.dat file, the index is not loaded correctly.

Comment: Ok, I've got it! The path needs to be set without the .dat extension. In my case: idx = index.Rtree(os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'gridIndex'))
Thanks for your help!